# Why is it mandatory to call a Super class's parameterized constructor inside subclass's parameterized constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, superclass

**The code below fails to compile:**

```
class Super
{ 
    int i = 0;    
    Super(String text)
    {
        i = 1; 
    } 
} 

class Sub extends Super
{
    Sub(String text)
    {
       ------------LINE 14------------
        i = 2; 
    }     
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Sub sub = new Sub("Hello"); 
        System.out.println(sub.i); 
    } 
}
```

But when I'm adding `super(text)` at line 14, it's working fine. Why is it so?

Comment: Because object needs to create all parent objects. class `Super` needs a parameter to create its instance, so you have to pass the argument this way to `Super`'s constructor

Comment: Mainly, because that's just how Java is defined. It will insert a call to `super()` for you, but it *won't* insert a call to `super(argsHere)` for you. It's just inconsistent in that way. Many other languages require that their equivalents to the `super()` call be explicit, too, which maintains consistency. Java just doesn't. Every language has quirks. *(Not dissing Java.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A constructor that doesn't have an explicit call to a super class constructor will be added an implicit call to the parameterless constructor (as if the `super();` statement was added a its first statement).

In your case, since the super class has a constructor with parameters, it has no parameterless constructor, so `super();` can't pass compilation, and you must call `super(text)` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.. :) I got it.

Answer (score 2):

because a 'Super' object needs to be created in order to create a 'Sub' object. and if you don't have any empty (default) c'tor you have to use one of the existing ones.